# Is a function with $0 \le f(x) \le x^2$ continuous at $x=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> If $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $0 \le f(x) \le x^2$, is it continuous at $x=0$ ?

---

I guess it is, because if $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence with $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = 0$ then 
$$
0 \le \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) \le \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n^2 = 0.$$ So $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = 0 = f(0)$ and so $f$ is continuous at $x=0$.

Is that correct?

Comment: you can't have $0 < f(0) < 0$.

Comment: You shall say that $0<f(x)<x^2$ for for all $x\neq -$

Comment: Do you know the squeeze lemma?

Comment: Sorry, just corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. But there's no need to introduce sequences here. You can just say that, since $\lim_{x\to0}0=\lim_{x\to0}x^2=0$ and since $(\forall x\in\mathbb{R}):0\leqslant f(x)\leqslant x^2$, then $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0=f(0)$.

Comment: Or to put it differently, "This is an application of the squeeze lemma, which is frequently useful and therefore worth knowing."

Comment: @JohnHughes The OP is obviously aware of the squeeze lemma, since he/she used for sequences. I just observed that it can be applied directly to functions.

Comment: I guess I was hoping that OP might look up "squeeze lemma" and discover that it's far more general than just the sequence form, or that some later reader might do so. It's a matter of pedagogical taste, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You have to note that:

> If $a_n \to a$(or $\limsup a_n=a$) and $a_n <b,\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ then $a \leq b$

So if you take sequences to examine continuity then it must be $0 \leq \limsup_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) \leq 0$

We use limsups because we don't know if the limit exists a priori.

So if you take $\leq$ in your above relation then you are correct.

But if your realtion was a strict inequality then you have to remember this property of sequences.

Of course if you have strict inequality then $f(0)$ must be defined a priori.